# WatchOS not listed in run destination in Xcode 7

Tags: ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7, watchos-2

I followed this tutorial (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-native-apple-watch-app-for-watchos-2--cms-24201) to create a demo watchOS 2 app. I can't get it to run in simulator as the watchOS simulator is not listed in run destination.

[image]

In the tutorial, the run destination showed up otherwise:

[image]

I have exhausted with any possible solutions that I can find on the Internet.

What have I missed? Or, is it a problem with Xcode?

I am running Xcode 7 (7A220) on OS X 10.10.5.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Checked the logs and it looks like CoreSimulator couldn't make connection with the devices.

Here the system.log:

```
Sep 26 00:37:04 Chertan kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 4789 [com.apple.CoreSi]
Sep 26 00:37:04 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 179~1 starting.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/26A5557E-A18E-463D-A983-2D97A2C5826A/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36049C9F-D5B2-454D-80C7-14BC8C0BBC5F/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/42A77066-16B7-4393-A705-293ACAA30912/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/50BAB20D-DF79-4728-800C-6A989333A600/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/680A57B1-A08C-43C6-878F-0C9DD05584C0/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7CB45BED-2A19-48E3-9EC7-827FFFB8B5E1/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ABDD6B28-7831-4576-B704-A1FE57F4559C/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BEC6C8F1-DB9F-4348-A0ED-01642077570D/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C2725678-5BC4-4D1B-9630-37162685DBA8/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C85E5433-0176-4091-B27E-9FEA89C6439C/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED850CEF-AD0E-4808-8425-8597DB197249/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:05 --- last message repeated 5 times ---
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[4817]: Notification is missing xpc_notification key: {
        notification = "availableDevices_changed";
    }
```

And CoreSimulator.log:

```
Sep 26 00:37:04 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Notice>: com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 179~1 starting.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/26A5557E-A18E-463D-A983-2D97A2C5826A/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36049C9F-D5B2-454D-80C7-14BC8C0BBC5F/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/42A77066-16B7-4393-A705-293ACAA30912/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/50BAB20D-DF79-4728-800C-6A989333A600/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/680A57B1-A08C-43C6-878F-0C9DD05584C0/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7CB45BED-2A19-48E3-9EC7-827FFFB8B5E1/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ABDD6B28-7831-4576-B704-A1FE57F4559C/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BEC6C8F1-DB9F-4348-A0ED-01642077570D/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C2725678-5BC4-4D1B-9630-37162685DBA8/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C85E5433-0176-4091-B27E-9FEA89C6439C/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED850CEF-AD0E-4808-8425-8597DB197249/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.dt.Xcode[3447] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4661] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4656] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4661] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4656] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local com.apple.iphonesimulator[4688] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:05 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4817] <Warning>: Notification is missing xpc_notification key: {
        notification = "availableDevices_changed";
    }
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Notice>: com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 179~1 starting.
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/26A5557E-A18E-463D-A983-2D97A2C5826A/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36049C9F-D5B2-454D-80C7-14BC8C0BBC5F/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/42A77066-16B7-4393-A705-293ACAA30912/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/50BAB20D-DF79-4728-800C-6A989333A600/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Notice>: SimDevice : iPhone 6 (52D0F6E4-1431-4181-9CA8-C28F2BDFB640) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6 } runtime={ SimRuntime : 9.0 (13A340) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0 } found in an inconsistent state: Loaded: 0 Running: 0 ... shutting down
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/680A57B1-A08C-43C6-878F-0C9DD05584C0/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7CB45BED-2A19-48E3-9EC7-827FFFB8B5E1/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ABDD6B28-7831-4576-B704-A1FE57F4559C/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BEC6C8F1-DB9F-4348-A0ED-01642077570D/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C2725678-5BC4-4D1B-9630-37162685DBA8/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C85E5433-0176-4091-B27E-9FEA89C6439C/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local CoreSimulatorService[4831] <Error>: Unable to load device.plist: /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED850CEF-AD0E-4808-8425-8597DB197249/device.plist
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4656] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local com.apple.dt.Xcode[3447] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4656] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4661] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
Sep 26 00:37:32 Chertan.local com.apple.ibtool[4661] <Warning>: CoreSimulatorService connection interrupted.  Resubscribing to notifications.
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates that Xcode.app can't communicate with CoreSimulatorService.  There were a lot of problems with this in Xcode 6.x.  Improvements were made in 7.0, but there are still some cases where you can run into issues.

If you have issues like this, the easiest thing to do is use the big hammer and reboot.

1. Don't rename Xcode.app as that's the main cause of getting into this state.
2. If you did rename Xcode.app, reboot to get to a clean state.

If you still have issues after the reboot, there may be hints as to what is going wrong in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log and /var/log/system.log.

Comment: Checked the logs and it looks like CoreSimulator couldn't make connection with the devices.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact log lines that you suspect.

Comment: I did not rename Xcode.app and restarted OS X many times and that wouldn't help either. I cleared the logs and devices in CoreSimulator and readied them and still not working.

Comment: Sep 26 11:06:46 Chertan locationd[5486]: Deleting /Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/21272670-640D-436E-8DD4-F4014D2F63DC/data/Library/Caches/locationd/glgps_nvs.bin if present
Sep 26 11:07:18 Chertan companionappd[5480]: (Error) WatchKit: <SPTransport.m __67-[SPTransport service:account:identifier:didSendWithSuccess:error:]_block_invoke:415> __67-[SPTransport service:account:identifier:didSendWithSuccess:error:]_block_invoke identifier (36967883-123B-443A-8F71-BF2CD2B23D4F), serviceName ((null)), success: 0 error, domain: com.apple.identityservices.error, code: 23

Comment: Sep 26 11:07:18 Chertan companionappd[5480]: (Note ) WatchKit: Running __96-[SPCompanionAppInstaller sendInstallationDataWithPath:dataType:name:info:installer:completion:]_block_invoke_2 in the installer queue for session 1
Sep 26 11:07:18 Chertan companionappd[5480]: (Note ) WatchKit: Running __96-[SPCompanionAppInstaller sendInstallationDataWithPath:dataType:name:info:installer:completion:]_block_invoke337 in the installer queue for session 1

Comment: Sep 26 11:07:18 Chertan companionappd[5480]: (Error) NPSLogging: <NPSDomainAccessor.m +[NPSDomainAccessor resolveActivePairedDevicePairingID:pairingDataStore:]:40> Failed to resolve pairing ID ((null)) or data store ((null)) for active device

Comment: Thanks for lighting up my path. Do you have any idea what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using terminal command xcrun simctl. Here's the outputs:

```
$ xcrun simctl list

== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s)
iPhone 6s Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
iPad Air 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2)
Apple Watch - 38mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm)
Apple Watch - 42mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-42mm)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 9.0 (9.0 - 13A340) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0)
watchOS 2.0 (2.0 - 13S343) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-2-0)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 9.0 --
    iPhone 6 (21272670-640D-436E-8DD4-F4014D2F63DC) (Booted)
-- watchOS 2.0 --
== Device Pairs ==
```

For some reasons that I don't know, Xcode 7 and Simulator did not recognize and setup watchOS 2.0 devices properly.

```
$ xcrun simctl create "Apple Watch 38mm" com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-2-0
```

Output:

```
EF648CAD-2C4B-4BD5-9C36-9D1DB3E3CD29
```

Then,

```
$ xcrun simctl boot EF648CAD-2C4B-4BD5-9C36-9D1DB3E3CD29

$ xcrun simctl pair EF648CAD-2C4B-4BD5-9C36-9D1DB3E3CD29 21272670-640D-436E-8DD4-F4014D2F63DC
```

This created a new paired device id:

```
AA86202A-A141-40AD-B3A6-61F755C39534

$ xcrun simctl list
== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s)
iPhone 6s Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
iPad Air 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2)
Apple Watch - 38mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm)
Apple Watch - 42mm (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-42mm)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 9.0 (9.0 - 13A340) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0)
watchOS 2.0 (2.0 - 13S343) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-2-0)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 9.0 --
    iPhone 6 (21272670-640D-436E-8DD4-F4014D2F63DC) (Booted)
-- watchOS 2.0 --
    Apple Watch 38mm (EF648CAD-2C4B-4BD5-9C36-9D1DB3E3CD29) (Booted)
== Device Pairs ==
AA86202A-A141-40AD-B3A6-61F755C39534 (connected)
    Watch: Apple Watch 38mm (EF648CAD-2C4B-4BD5-9C36-9D1DB3E3CD29) (Booted)
    Phone: iPhone 6 (21272670-640D-436E-8DD4-F4014D2F63DC) (Booted)
```

Now, I have created a device pairs and connected. Go back to Xcode and I have the paired device listed in run destination:

[image]

Comment: Before you start running your apps, exit Xcode and all the simulator and shutdown the devices using the simctl command. After having all the devices shutdown, start your Xcode and run your app.